# Looking to filter results

Tags: zapier

I want to add a filter to a **Zapier** call.

It seems like I cannot get it right with the following code.

```
return z.request(options).then((response) => {
  response.throwForStatus();
  const results = response.json;

  const col = results["DatabaseColumns"].map((item) => {
    return {
      ...item,
      id: item["ColumnName"],
      if 'IsCustom': true,
    };
  });
}
```

Without the `if 'IsCustom': true` the code works and pulls all the fields (custom ones and not custom ones as well).

I am sure that I either need a different statement or it is in the wrong place.

Can anyone help?

7/16: This is what I have now, and I tried some other versions that do not work.

```
    return z.request(options).then((response) => {
  response.throwForStatus();
  const results = response.json;

const col = results.DatabaseColumns.filter((item) => item.IsCustom).map((item) => {
    return {
      ...items,
      id: items["DatabaseColumns"],
    };
  });

  return col});
```

I hope you can help clean this up.

Answer (score 0):

> Without the `if 'IsCustom': true` the code works

That's because that snippet is invalid JS, so when it's removed the code is at least running.

It looks like your goal is to filter the data that's returned. If so JS has a filter method for arrays. Try:

```js
const col = results.DatabaseColumns.filter((item) => item.IsCustom).map( // ...
```

make sure to return `col` at the bottom of the function, too!

Comment: Thank you! I got that in there an I am not sure if the rest is correct since I am getting errors.
'return z.request(options).then((response) => {
  response.throwForStatus();
  const results = response.json;

const col = results.DatabaseColumns.filter((item) => item.IsCustom).map(item) => {

    return {
      ...item,
      col: item["DatabaseColums"],
    };
  });

  return col 
}); 

'

Comment: can you update your original question with the updated code and screenshots of your errors?

Comment: Done. I was trying to figure out how to add the code in a reply and it did not work. Thanks for the info not that.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find a solution!

```
const options = {
  url: 'https://edapi.campaigner.com/v1/Database',
  method: 'GET',
  headers: {
    'X-API-KEY': bundle.authData.ApiKey
  },
  params: {
    'ApiKey': bundle.authData.ApiKey
  }
};

return z.request(options).then((response) => {
  response.throwForStatus();
  const results = response.json;

const col = results.DatabaseColumns.filter((item) => item.IsCustom).map((item) => {
    return {
      ...item,
      id: item["ColumnName"],
    };
  });

  return col});
```